# Is it a bad practice to use an identity column to determine the order of row creation?

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use a SQL Server identity column to determine the inserted order of rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708607/can-i-use-a-sql-server-identity-column-to-determine-the-inserted-order-of-rows)

If an identity column is reseeded, then it can not be used be used to determine the order of row insertion, but I have no reason to ever reseed the identity.

Are there any reasons why I should not use the identity column to determine the order of creation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708607/can-i-use-a-sql-server-identity-column-to-determine-the-inserted-order-of-rows

Comment: As to your question about granularity of datetime.  Values are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds, so if you expect succession to occur quicker than this (i.e. bulk insert) then possibly not.  Documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not considered a good practice. For example, two processes doing inserts on a table in simultaneous transactions can in some servers have chunks of ids assigned to them, so any row inserted from one transaction will have a lesser id than any row inserted from the other transaction. Also, this can sometimes cause gaps in sequence of ids. And there may be also other scenarios something unexpected might happen.

In short, autoincremented ids are **not always** guaranteed to a be a continuous and ascending sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Because it wouldn't be reliable would be the reason I would not use it. You might have two processes ask simultaneously for identity values and process 1 got the first value and process 2 got the second value but process 2 actually finished the transaction earlier and thus was inserted earlier. A datetime field for date inserted is the only reliable choice if you want to know the order that records were actually inserted.

Comment: That problem is a non-issue, I will only using looking for `max`, `min`, or doing an `ORDER BY`.  Also, the date will not work, my records are created quickly enough that they will have the same date.

Comment: @mikerobi - Another issue is *guaranteeing* that you never (nor any DBA now or ever in the future) use IDENTITY_INSERT to insert a value into a gap created by a delete. If anything, a date in combination with the identity column to get around the lack of granularity would be better. If using SQL Server 2008, you can use DateTime2 and get more than enough granularity to use just that column instead of relying on the identity column.